# OpenCV: How to save detected face to SD Card location in android?

Tags: java, android, opencv

Can anyone suggest me how to save Image file to SD card location in Android, when Face is detected using **OpenCV**.

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this to convert mat to bitmap:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(matWithFace.cols(), matWithFace.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(matWithFace, bitmap);
```

and then save it to file like this :

```
try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
    out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```